# How to center arrows verticaly relative to the picture in slick slider when i have text under image?

Tags: javascript, css, slick.js

On picture you can see thet my arrows are top:50% relative to height of slide container
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjEZh.png

Comment: Can you post your code and css?

Comment: the issue is very common, so you probably could have easily found an answer on Google

Comment: Im trying to find solution but no lucky

Comment: I dont have any css, im just using css from slick.css

Answer (score -1):

I made a quick demo on Codepen: https://codepen.io/basti-n/pen/NWNRKYX?editors=1111

```
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="arrow-left"><</div>
    <img src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random.jpg" alt="elephant">
  <div class="arrow-right">></div>
  </div>
    <div class="description">
      <caption>Lorem Ipsum</caption>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

  img {
    height: 300px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 10px;
  }
}

.description {
  margin-top: 12px;
}
```

Comment: This needs to have behaviour of slick slider

Comment: Provide a codepen and we can provide you with an answer about integrating what I did independant of the slick slider with regards to centering the arrows.

Comment: function ceteringArrows() {
        let positionTop = $(".blog-detail-slider-picture").height() / 2 + 'px';
        $(".slick-arrow").css("top", positionTop);
    }